# Are all the NP-complete problems have strong reductions?

Tags: p-vs-np

Are all the [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problems have strong reductions? If I find a polynomial solution to one **NP-complete** problem, can I state that `P = NP`?

Comment: yes, if you show that one of the NP-complete problems is in P P=NP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't seem to have a correct grasp of the concept of NP-completeness. Every NP complete problem has a reduction to every other NP complete problem. That is, there is a poly-time reduction *from* SAT *to* HAMPATH.

Thus, if you have a polynomial solution for HAMPATH, you can solve any case of SAT in polynomial time, so P=NP.

Comment: How do you prove that a problem is NP complete? Do you need to do a reduction from all other problems? There are thousands of them.

Comment: That's exactly the beauty of reductions: they are transitive. Once you show on a problem $A$ that it is NP complete, then in order to show that problem $B$ is NP complete, all you need to show is that $B$ is in NP, and that there is a reduction from $A$ to $B$. But how do you get the "first" NP complete problem - well, the Cook-Levin theorem shows a reduction from *every* problem in NP (there are infinitely many of those, not just thousands) to SAT.